# Cannot invoke 'reduce' with an argument list of type ''

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, encryption, xcode6.1

I was using the "Swift encrypt/decrypt string using XOR" on this [website](https://gist.github.com/alskipp/016c8ba96352e5c74bf2) to encrypt my string in my project. It worked fine with xCode 6.1, but after I updated my xCode to 6.4, it's not working anymore.

```
func encrypt(message:String, key:String) -> String {
    return reduce(Zip2(message, key), "") { $0 + self.encrypt($1) }
}
```

xCode said: `Cannot invoke 'reduce' with an argument list of type '(Zip2<String, String>, String, (_, _) -> _)'`

Can someone please help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: Add parentheses around `(Zip2(message, key), "")`

Comment: This is what I got in xCode: `func reduce<S : SequenceType, U>(sequence: S, initial: U, combine: @noescape (U, S.Generator.Element) -> U) -> U`

Comment: @Kendel, `reduce` is from Foundation.

Comment: @Kametrixom that does not change anything, the parenthese are correct so far.

Comment: @edwardit you are using swift 1, right?

Comment: @luk2302 Sr, how do I know which swift version am I using?

Comment: Can you post the full class? My guess is that the issue is in the declaration of the called encrypt func (the one called with self.encrypt($1)).

Comment: @edwardit: The website that you linked to has also code for Swift 1.2 (encrypt_xor2.swift), which compiles just fine in Xcode 6.4.

Comment: @MarioZannone I posted the github webpage on my post. I am using the `encrypt_xor1.swift` in that website.

Comment: @MartinR Are they the same? I'm not good at this encrypt thing :(

Comment: @edwardt The website uses encrypt($1). Instead your code reads self.encrypt($1). It is not the same code.

Comment: @edwardit: That website has code for both Swift 1.0 and Swift 1.2. Both are followed by *example calls*, which gives the *same output* for both versions. So what is your question?

Comment: @MartinR Sorry I didn't read the whole code. It works fine now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MarioZannone I got it to work now. Thanks for your concern :)